# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception, In my flutter project how can i solve it?

Tags: flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\flutterproject\firstproject\android\untitled\android\build.gradle' line: 27
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> > 'org.gradle.api.file.DirectoryProperty org.gradle.api.file.ProjectLayout.directoryProperty(org.gradle.api.provider.Provider)'

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

> File → Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and
> uncheck Enable Instant Run.

Hope it works.